# List doesn't render children when split into a component

Tags: reactjs

Well the title describes my problem, for some reason when my unordered list is writtin in Jsx it renders like you would expect, but when i try to split it into a reusable component, items in list doesn't render, and no errors are thrown at me.

List is imported correctly, i'm unsure what causes the issue.

Works:

```
  return (
    <header className={headerStyle}>
      <nav className={navStyle}>
        <ul className={ulStyle}>
          <LinkItem value="home" url="/" />
          <LinkItem value="menu" url="/menu" />
          <LinkItem value="gallery" url="/gallery" />
          <LinkItem value="testiminials" url="/testiminials" />
          <LinkItem value="contact us" url="/contact" />
        </ul>
        <div className={accountStyle}></div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
```

This doesn't:

```
  return (
    <header className={headerStyle}>
      <nav className={navStyle}>
        <List>
          <LinkItem value="home" url="/" />
          <LinkItem value="menu" url="/menu" />
          <LinkItem value="gallery" url="/gallery" />
          <LinkItem value="testiminials" url="/testiminials" />
          <LinkItem value="contact us" url="/contact" />
        </List>
        <div className={accountStyle}></div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
```

List.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { css } from "emotion";

const ulStyle = css`
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
`;

const List = () => {
  return <ul className={ulStyle}></ul>;
};

export default List;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to pass the `props.children` to `render`:

```js
const List = (props) => {
  return <ul className={ulStyle}>{props.children}</ul>;
};
```

That's because the items inside the `Link` are not passed by themselves and you need to pass it to your component.